# Trigger.io Build error

Tags: trigger.io

Hi since yesterday i can't build my project and getting this log

```
[INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.54
[INFO] Your app configuration has changed since your last build of this platform, performing a remote build of your app. Once this is downloaded future builds will be faster.
[INFO] Starting new build
[INFO] This could take a while, but will only happen again if you modify config.json
[ERROR] build failed: [  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:53,206 -- inspecting build id 17977
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,509 -- running build "ios task  17977"
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,510 -- reading system config file from /opt/stable/SYSTEM_BUILD_CONFIG.json
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,511 -- adding "/mnt/stable/platform-source/v1.4.48/generate" to sys.path
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,511 -- set sys.path to be [u'/mnt/stable/platform-source/v1.4.48/generate', '/opt/stable/website', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/src/django-registration', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/src/validictory', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/src/django-haystack-dev', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/lib/python27.zip', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/lib/python2.7', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/Extras/lib/python', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/opt/stable/stable-python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,877 -- Enabled platforms: [u'ios']
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,878 -- Migrating config.json from version 3 to version 4
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,881 -- <ForgeTask (ios)> running...
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,891 -- <ForgeTask (ios)> script:
[{'do': {'preprocess_config': ()}},
 {'do': {'resolve_urls': ('plugins.activations.config.activations.[].scripts.[]',
                          'plugins.activations.config.activations.[].styles.[]',
                          'plugins.icons.config.chrome',
                          'plugins.icons.config.safari',
                          'plugins.icons.config.firefox',
                          'plugins.launchimage.config.android',
                          'plugins.launchimage.config.android-landscape',
                          'plugins.button.config.default_icon',
                          'plugins.button.config.default_popup',
                          'plugins.button.config.default_icons.*')}},
 {'do': {'addon_source': 'common-v2'}},
 {'do': {'addon_source': 'plugin/schema'}},
 {'do': {'addon_source': 'ios/ForgeCore'}, 'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'addon_source': 'ios/app'}, 'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'addon_source': 'ios/js'}, 'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'prepare_plugin_override': ()}},
 {'do': {'fallback_to_default_toolbar_icon': ()}},
 {'do': {'copy_files': {'from': 'common-v2/forge',
                        'to': 'ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'common-v2/api-prefix.js'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'common-v2/config.js'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'common-v2/api.js'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'common-v2/modules/is/common.js'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'common-v2/modules/is/ios.js'},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios,ios-inspector'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'common-v2/modules/logging/default.js'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'common-v2/modules/internal/default.js'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'common-v2/modules/event/mobile.js'},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'android,an-inspector,ios,ios-inspector'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'common-v2/modules/event/common.js'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'common-v2/reload.js'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'common-v2/tools.js'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'ios/js/api-ios.js'},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'common-v2/api-expose.js'}},
 {'do': {'add_to_all_js': 'common-v2/api-suffix.js'}},
 {'do': {'find_and_replace': {'find': 'kForgeLogLevel = @"DEBUG";',
                              'in': ('ios/ForgeCore/ForgeCore/utils/ForgeLog.m',),
                              'replace': 'kForgeLogLevel = @"${logging_level}";'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'download_and_extract_plugins': ()}, 'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'add_plugins_ios': ()}, 'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'minify_in_place': 'ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js'},
  'when': {'is_external': (), 'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'xcode_build': 'ios/app'}, 'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'remove_files': 'common-v2'}},
 {'do': {'rename_files': {'from': 'ios/app/dist', 'to': 'development/ios'}},
  'when': {'platform_is': 'ios'}},
 {'do': {'move_output': 'development'}},
 {'do': {'remember_build_output_location': ()}}]
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,891 -- preprocessing configuration
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,892 -- copying source directory /mnt/stable/platform-source/v1.4.48/common-v2 to common-v2
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,902 -- copying source directory /mnt/stable/platform-source/v1.4.48/plugin/schema to plugin/schema
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,903 -- copying source directory /mnt/stable/platform-source/v1.4.48/ios/ForgeCore to ios/ForgeCore
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,925 -- copying source directory /mnt/stable/platform-source/v1.4.48/ios/app to ios/app
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,940 -- copying source directory /mnt/stable/platform-source/v1.4.48/ios/js to ios/js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:55,941 -- copying source directory /mnt/stable/platform-source/v1.4.48/plugins to plugins
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,253 -- moving default toolbar icon into place
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,254 -- settings browser_action.default_icon
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,255 -- copying common-v2/forge to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,323 -- concatenating common-v2/api-prefix.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,323 -- appended common-v2/api-prefix.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,323 -- concatenating common-v2/config.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,324 -- appended common-v2/config.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,326 -- concatenating common-v2/api.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,366 -- appended common-v2/api.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,367 -- concatenating common-v2/modules/is/common.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,367 -- appended common-v2/modules/is/common.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,371 -- concatenating common-v2/modules/is/ios.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,371 -- appended common-v2/modules/is/ios.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,378 -- concatenating common-v2/modules/logging/default.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,384 -- appended common-v2/modules/logging/default.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,385 -- concatenating common-v2/modules/internal/default.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,385 -- appended common-v2/modules/internal/default.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,392 -- concatenating common-v2/modules/event/mobile.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,392 -- appended common-v2/modules/event/mobile.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,394 -- concatenating common-v2/modules/event/common.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,394 -- appended common-v2/modules/event/common.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,394 -- concatenating common-v2/reload.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,394 -- appended common-v2/reload.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,395 -- concatenating common-v2/tools.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,395 -- appended common-v2/tools.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,395 -- concatenating ios/js/api-ios.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,395 -- appended ios/js/api-ios.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,397 -- concatenating common-v2/api-expose.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,398 -- appended common-v2/api-expose.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,398 -- concatenating common-v2/api-suffix.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,398 -- appended common-v2/api-suffix.js to ios/app/ForgeInspector/assets/forge/all.js
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,399 -- replacing kForgeLogLevel = @"DEBUG"; with u'kForgeLogLevel = @"CRITICAL";'
[WARNING] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,400 -- No files were found to match pattern "ios/ForgeCore/ForgeCore/utils/ForgeLog.m"
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,400 -- Downloading plugins
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,400 -- Downloading plugin: geolocation
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,400 -- Plugin already downloaded: geolocation
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,400 -- Downloaded plugin: geolocation
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,400 -- Downloading plugin: launchimage
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,400 -- Plugin already downloaded: launchimage
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,401 -- Downloaded plugin: launchimage
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,401 -- Downloading plugin: parameters
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,401 -- Plugin already downloaded: parameters
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,401 -- Downloaded plugin: parameters
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,401 -- Downloading plugin: partners
[  DEBUG] 2013-06-13 11:46:57,401 -- Downloading plugin id: notahash
[   INFO] 2013-06-13 11:46:58,983 -- cleaning up source directories
[  ERROR] 2013-06-13 11:46:58,983 -- File is not a zip file
```

Comment: Yup.  Frustrating.  Mac OS build seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your config.json file is slightly wrong, the `partners` section should be in the root of the config rather than under the `modules` section.